# Getting error in Django: matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

So basically, I have a Friend model, and in the model is all the code, and then in the views, I have some code for friends as well, and I am getting this error

```
matching query does not exist.
```

I have tried all the solutions I have found online, however none have worked yet, so I came here to try and find the answer. This is using the latest version of Django.

Relevant models.py

```py
class Friend(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='owner',null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @classmethod
    def make_friend(cls,current_user,new_friend):
        friend,created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user = current_user
        )
        friend.users.add(new_friend)

    @classmethod
    def lose_friend(cls,current_user,new_friend):
        friend,created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user = current_user
        )
        friend.users.remove(new_friend)
```

This is the relevant views.py
Sorry if it's a bit long

```py
class PostListView(SelectRelatedMixin,TagMixin,generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'mainapp/post_list.html'
    selected_related = ("user","group")
    queryset = models.Post.objects.all()

    def get(self,request):
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
        friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
        friends = friend.users.all()

        context = {
            'users':users,'friends':friends
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(PostListView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['user_groups'] = Group.objects.filter(members__in=[self.request.user.id])
        context['all_groups'] = Group.objects.all()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')

def change_friends(request,operation,pk):
    friend = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if operation == 'add':
        Friend.make_friend(request.user,friend)
    elif operation == 'remove':
        Friend.lose_friend(request.user,friend)
    return redirect('mainapp:post_list')
```

So the actual error is happening in the `get()` method with the `friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)` line.

Here is the urls.py file.

```py
#post list url

path('posts/',views.PostListView.as_view(),name='post_list'),
# connect url

path('connect/<operation>/<pk>',views.change_friends,name='change_friends'),
```

And here is the relevant code in `post_list.html`

```html
<p>People to connect with</p>
{% for user in users %}
<a href="#">
    <p>{{ user.username }}</p>
</a>
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<p>Friends</p>
{% for friend in friends %}
<a href="#">
    <p>{{ friend.username }}</p>
</a>
{% endif %}
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error, and all the solutions online have not solved this.

I am expecting no errors to occur, and for the users and friends to work properly, however this is not the case and I am recieving this error.
Thank you for any help you are able to give :)

Comment: Well you're getting this because... there is no Friend matching that query.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: I don't see what is unclear about either my comment or the original error message. You're querying for a Friend object whose `current_user` field is equal to the logged-in user; Django is telling you that no such Friend exists in the database.

Comment: @jeremy_lord this has nothing to do with your admin,  this has to do with what's in your **database**. May I kindly suggest you do the official Django tutorial, then read the `models` documentation ? This will be __much__ more useful than "trying any solution you find online".

Comment: I found the root of the cause. So everything does in fact work when I go into the admin and manually give the user a friend, however this obviously isn't efficient, so I am going to figure out a way so that it automatically stores data